# ui:repeat and h:panelGrid

Tags: jsf, facelets, mojarra

When using something like

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <ui:repeat var="o" value="#{mybean.list}">
        <h:outputText value="#{o.text}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

with lets say 10 list entries I only get 1 row e.g.: one tr with 1 td whereas when I use c:forEach i get 10  (but c:forEach is in fact evil, it messes up everything with ajax)

I use mojarra 1.2 - is this a typical Mojarra bug which does not exist in the MyFaces implementation? Will it disappear in 2.x of the Mojarra releases?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The output is fully as expected and specified. The `<ui:repeat>` is a render time tag, not a view build time tag like `<c:forEach>`. After building the view, `<h:panelGrid>` ends up with 1 child component (the `<ui:repeat>` itself), not with *n* `<h:outputText>` components like as with `<c:forEach>`.

You need a `<h:dataTable>` instead. It's designed for exactly this purpose.

```
<h:dataTable var="o" value="#{mybean.list}">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{o.text}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)