# Access added values through jQuery UI widget inside ui:repeat in JSF

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, tag-it

- I have added a ui:repeat within a ul-list to produce a unordered list
- Through [jQuery Tag-It widget](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) the list get´s nicely editable (unfortunately primefaces doen't have a similar component yet)
- when saving the form i can't access the new created values (only the values of the other primefaces components)

**XHTML**

```
<ul id="keywordList">
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.selectedObject.keywords}" var="keyword">
    <li><h:outputText value="#{keyword.name}" /></li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

**Bean**

```
public class Bean implements Serializable {
    private MyObject selectedObject;
}
```

**Model**

```
public List<String> getKeywords() {
    return keywords;
} 

public void setKeywords(List<String> keywords) {
    this.keywords = keywords;
}
```

Any idea, how i can access the values which are added to the UL-List?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: The bean is session scoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its [documentation](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown) and [demos](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html) the jQuery tag-it plugin autocreates a hidden input element with the (configureable) name syntax `item[tags][]`. You should be able to grab it from the HTTP request parameter values map by [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterValuesMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestHeaderValuesMap%28%29) in JSF as follows:

```
String[] tags = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getRequestParameterValuesMap().get("item[tags][]");
```

You could also set it as a managed property, but this requires the bean to be request scoped.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{paramValues['item[tags][]']}")
private String[] tags;
```

Comment: Hi BalusC, awesome! It works. Actually i was just reading your [answer to ui:repeat and h:panelGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945544/uirepeat-and-hpanelgrid) and i thought my requirement is not going to work as `<ui:repeat>` is a render time tag, but obviously i misunderstood. BTW: What about creating a component like TagIt  to [OmniFaces](https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/)? ;-)

Comment: It's by the way already been requested 5 hours earlier today: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4166&q=%22new%20component%22&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary Was it you?

Comment: Voted! And actually i already posted a [feature request to PF](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4166)