# In JSF is it valid to have a ui:repeater inside a h:dataTable

Tags: java, jsf-2

Is it valid to have a JSF ui:repeater inside a h:dataTable for dynamically defining the columns? The method getFieldNames(...) is never called even though it is referenced from the html. The method getEntities is called. Any ideas?

```
@Named(value = "data")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {

    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    public CustomBean() {
        final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        for (final String fieldName : new String[]
            {"ColumnOne", "ColumnTwo", "ColumnThree"}) {
            data.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {

                {
                    put(fieldName, fieldName + "_" + i.getAndDecrement());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public List<String> getFieldNames() {
        // THIS METHOD DOES NOT GET CALLED
        return new ArrayList<String>(data.get(0).keySet());
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getEntities() {
        return data;
    }
}



<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:dataTable value="#{data.entities}" var="entity">
            <ui:repeat var="fieldName" value="#{data.fieldNames}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{fieldName}</f:facet>
                    #{entity.get(fieldName)}
                </h:column>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Following Q/As may sched some light on your topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945544/uirepeat-and-hpanelgrid, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use ui:repeat for having dynamic columns inside a data table. You can try a component library such as Primefaces or Richfaces, which allows you to have dynamic columns easily. In [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) link you can see Primefaces' dynamic columns feature in action.
Also, you may try to create the table model dynamically in the backing bean.This BalusC's [tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com.ar/2006/06/using-datatables.html#PopulateDatatable) explains how to do it.