# I'm stuck on dynamic panel

Tags: primefaces, selectonemenu

I met a problem for two days. nowhere I advance
my problem is to make a dynamic content in a panel according to the selected element in the list p: selectOneMenu

```
    <h:outputLabel value="Categorie :"  />  
                <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{composantbean.selectedCategoryId}" required="true" >  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select categorie" itemValue="" />  
                    <f:selectItems  value="#{composantbean.listcat}" var="cat" itemValue="#{cat.nomCat}" itemLabel="#{cat.nomCat}" /> 
                    <p:ajax update="panl"  event="change" listener="#{composantbean.catListener()}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>  


<p:panel id="panl" header ="Caracteristique selon la categorie" toggleable="true" rendered="true" >

            <h:panelGrid  id="panlecart" columns="2" cellpadding="5" rendered="true">
            <c:forEach items="#{composantbean.categorie.proprietes}"  var="var">

            <h:outputText value="#{var.nomProp}"/>
            <h:inputText value="" />

            </c:forEach>
         </h:panelGrid>
          </p:panel>
```

content appears this is true but unfortunately it is not synchronized is displayed shift
but if I use another `<p: selectOneMenu id = "panel"` content is displayed and synchronized

Haw can I fixe my prblem .Please and thank you in advance

Comment: Using c:foreach is a bad idea in JSF.  You should prefer ui:repeat.  This is due to life cycle differences and could lead to problems like you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lucas said, it is a bad idea using c:foreach (and all kind of JSTL) in JSF, especially with ajax.
Here are references you should read, to know more about JSTL in JSF:

1. [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)
2. https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat

Using ui:repeat in h:panelGrid is not recommended also. You may read the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945544/uirepeat-and-hpanelgrid).

So, IMHO, you should try another approach, such as using dataTable, as stated in above link.
Or, you could use html's table tag (<table>) as replacement of h:panelGrid, with html's tr and td tag inside ui:repeat. For example:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Categorie :"  />  
<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{composantbean.selectedCategoryId}" required="true" >  
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select categorie" itemValue="" />  
  <f:selectItems  value="#{composantbean.listcat}" var="cat" itemValue="#{cat.nomCat}" itemLabel="#{cat.nomCat}" /> 
  <p:ajax update="panl"  event="change" listener="#{composantbean.catListener()}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>  

<p:panel id="panl" header ="Caracteristique selon la categorie" toggleable="true" rendered="true" >

  <table>
  <ui:repeat value="#{composantbean.categorie.proprietes}"  var="var">
    <tr>
      <td><h:outputText value="#{var.nomProp}" /></td>
      <td><h:inputText value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </ui:repeat>
  </table>
</p:panel>
```